# How to Learn PC's Charset

Tags: windows-7, charset

How to learn my pc's character set?

For example when I open any iso-8859-... arabic file in my computer by notepad, I see nonsense characters. The file is taken from an arabic windows. And my windows language is Turkish. I think there is character set conflict.

- What is the charset of Arabic
- What is the charset of Turkish
- How can I view my computer default charset used by notepad or any other program.

Any helps are welcome...

Edit1

> The file charset looks ansi. I know that there is windows charset behind ansi, such as for Arabic ISO-8859-6 etc.

Comment: The file you're opening is probably UTF-8 and should be opened as such.

Comment: Not so, file looks ansi. And I know that behind ansi current charset is available.

Comment: ANSI is a subset of UTF-8. So a UTF-8 file can "look" ANSI. You can also change window's locale to your choosing in Control Panel under `Region and Language`. See (http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-system-locale#1TC=windows-7)

Comment: I'd like to learn ISO-xxxx-x set.

Comment: [National Language Support (NLS) API Reference](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/msdn/goglobal/default.mspx)